# animated element position middle center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a problem with this code in `Chrome`. When you click on the checkbox the text/checkbox change position/padding/margin something.. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/k5tswhsx/

## HTML

```
<input id="inp" type="checkbox" />
<div id="cb" class="inp_checkbox"></div>
Test
```

## JS

```
function init_checkbox(input_id, check_id){
    var input = $('#'+input_id), checkbox = $('#'+check_id).html('<div></div>'), options = {
        duration : 200
    };

    checkbox.click(function(){
        input.prop('checked', !input.prop('checked')).focus().change();
    }), inner = $('<div></div>').appendTo(checkbox.find('div:first'));

    input.focus(function(){
        checkbox.addClass('focus');
    })
    .blur(function(){
        checkbox.removeClass('focus');
    })
    .change(function(){
        if(input.prop('checked')){
            inner.animate({
                height : 10,
                width : 10
            }, options);
        }
        else{
            inner.animate({
                height : 0,
                width : 0
            }, options);
        }
    });
}

init_checkbox('inp', 'cb');
```

## CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
.inp_checkbox {
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #919191;
    border-radius:1px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.inp_checkbox.focus {
    border-color:#007fff !important;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #007fff, 0 0 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.inp_checkbox {
    display:inline-block;
}
.inp_checkbox > div {
    display:flex;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:1px;
    height:18px;
    width:18px;
}
.inp_checkbox > div > div {
    background:#424242;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap "test" in a span tag. Add `float:left` to both the input and span tag.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k5tswhsx/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<input id="inp" type="checkbox" />
<div id="cb" class="inp_checkbox"></div>
<span>Test</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
    float: left;
}
.inp_checkbox {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float your div:

```
.inp_checkbox > div {
    display:flex;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:1px;
    height:18px;
    width:18px;
    float:left;
}
```

If you also want to center your text, put it in a container as well and position it with `line-height`;